# How was The Great Gilly Hopkins revised for 2015?

Tags: textual-history, katherine-paterson, the-great-gilly-hopkins

I'm reading Katherine Paterson's *The Great Gilly Hopkins* for the first time. It's the "Revised paperback edition, 2015" of a book copyrighted in 1978, according to the copyright page. Based on the content of the book, I'm guessing some or all of those revisions may be bowdlerizations of the word "nigger". But I wonder whether anyone can supply a complete list of the revisions.

Comment: The [1978 Penguin edition](https://archive.org/details/greatgillyhopkin0001pate) and the [2015 Harper edition](https://archive.org/details/greatgillyhopkin0000pate_v0v3) are both available for loan from the Internet Archive, so you could compare them yourself!

Comment: Of the copies Gareth linked, the '78 edition has American spellings and the 2015 edition has British English spelling. Do you know whether your edition is a UK one? Other than that a quick search ascertains that there are no obvious racial epithets in either, where the character is meant to be thinking them text tends to tail off with a  dash, rather than articulate it. The newer edition also corrects at least one typo that I spotted. I doubt that anyone is going to have a comprehensive list of every change.